# Visual Studio Code Debugger shows 0 for a double that is NaN

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, nan, godot

While searching for why the double averagePrice in my program was NaN I stumbled upon this weird behaviour for the Visual Studio Code Debugger. The Debugger shows averagePrice = 0 whereas double.IsNaN is true and GODOT.GD.Print(averagePrice) prints NaN.

```
            if (double.IsNaN(averagePrice))
            {
                Godot.GD.Print(averagePrice);
            }
```

I checked back my code in Visual Studio as a Console Application for verification, but Viusal Studio seems to get it right. My only guess is that the Godot Extension causes this issue:

[Visual Studio Code extensions used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIRyo.png)

I am not sure if help is possible, but any idea on how to fix this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: For Reference and since there is another error happening with the same variable, here is the full method:

```
    public void ResolveOffers(Item commodity)
    {
        int demand = 0;
        int supply = 0;
        int unitsSold = 0;
        double averagePrice = 0;

        foreach (ProfessionType professionType in EarningsByProfession.Keys)
        {
            EarningsByProfession[professionType] = 0;
        }

        bool hasDemand = _bidsForCommodity.ContainsKey(commodity);
        if (hasDemand)
            if (_bidsForCommodity[commodity].Count <= 0)
                hasDemand = false;
        bool hasSupply = _asksForCommodity.ContainsKey(commodity);
        if (hasSupply)
            if (_asksForCommodity[commodity].Count <= 0)
                hasSupply = false;

        if (hasDemand && hasSupply)
        {
            List<Bid> bids = _bidsForCommodity[commodity];
            List<Ask> asks = _asksForCommodity[commodity];

            foreach (Bid bid in bids)
            {
                demand += (int)bid.Quantity; //needs to be extracted so that the reports can note it even if no trades happen
            }

            foreach (Ask ask in asks)
            {
                supply += (int)ask.Quantity;
            }
                
            bids.Shuffle();
            asks.Shuffle();

            bids.Sort((x, y) => y.Price.CompareTo(x.Price));
            asks.Sort((x, y) => x.Price.CompareTo(y.Price));

            while (bids.Count > 0 && asks.Count > 0)
            {
                Bid buyer = bids[0];
                Ask seller = asks[0];

                if(seller.Agent.UniqueID == 35 && commodity == Item.Food)
                {
                    int cycles = Main.Cycles;
                }

                
                double clearingPrice = (buyer.Price + seller.Price) / 2;
                uint quantityTraded = Math.Min(buyer.Quantity, seller.Quantity);

                buyer.Quantity = MaximumAffordableAmount(quantityTraded, clearingPrice, buyer.Agent.Currency);
                                  
                if (quantityTraded > 0)
                {
                    double totalTransactionPrice = clearingPrice * quantityTraded;
                    unitsSold += (int)quantityTraded;
                    averagePrice += totalTransactionPrice; 

                    if(double.IsNaN(averagePrice))
                        Godot.GD.Print("Ohje!");
                    if(averagePrice < 1)
                        Godot.GD.Print("Auch sehr Ohje!");

                    buyer.Quantity -= quantityTraded;
                    seller.Quantity -= quantityTraded;

                    buyer.QuantityTraded = quantityTraded;
                    seller.QuantityTraded = quantityTraded;

                    buyer.ClearingPrice = clearingPrice;
                    seller.ClearingPrice = clearingPrice;



                    if (!EarningsByProfession.ContainsKey(buyer.Agent.Profession.Type))
                        EarningsByProfession.Add(buyer.Agent.Profession.Type, -1 * totalTransactionPrice);
                    EarningsByProfession[buyer.Agent.Profession.Type] -= totalTransactionPrice;

                    if (!EarningsByProfession.ContainsKey(seller.Agent.Profession.Type))
                        EarningsByProfession.Add(seller.Agent.Profession.Type, totalTransactionPrice);
                    EarningsByProfession[seller.Agent.Profession.Type] += totalTransactionPrice;

                    seller.PercentOfOrderUnfilled = 1 - (double)seller.QuantityTraded/(buyer.Quantity + buyer.QuantityTraded);
                    buyer.PercentageOfOfferFilled = (double)buyer.QuantityTraded/(seller.Quantity + seller.QuantityTraded); // (double)seller.QuantityTraded/(buyer.Quantity + buyer.QuantityTraded);

                    seller.Agent.RemoveFromInventory(commodity, quantityTraded);
                    seller.Agent.AddCurrency(clearingPrice * quantityTraded); // totalTransactionPrice

                    buyer.Agent.AddToInventory(commodity, quantityTraded);
                    buyer.Agent.RemoveCurrency(clearingPrice * quantityTraded);

                   // _marketData.UpdateData(demand, supply, unitsSold, averagePrice/unitsSold, commodity);
                    _marketDataContainer.Write(commodity, demand, supply, unitsSold, averagePrice/unitsSold);

                    buyer.Agent.PriceUpdateFromBid(buyer);
                    seller.Agent.PriceUpdateFromAsk(seller);
                }

                if (seller.Quantity == 0)
                    asks.Remove(seller);
                if (buyer.Quantity == 0)
                    bids.Remove(buyer);
            }

            ResolveRejectedAsks(asks);
            ResolveRejectedBids(bids);
        }
        else
        {
            int testint = Main.Cycles;
        }

        if (double.IsNaN(averagePrice))
        {
            Godot.GD.Print(averagePrice);
            Godot.GD.Print(averagePrice == 0);
        }

        if (unitsSold > 0)
            averagePrice /= unitsSold;
        else
            averagePrice = 0;

        if (double.IsNaN(averagePrice))
        {
        }

        if (Main.Cycles >= 2)
        {

        }

        _marketDataContainer.Write(commodity, demand, supply, unitsSold, averagePrice);
        //_marketData.UpdateData(demand, supply, unitsSold, averagePrice, commodity);
        /*
        else if (_bidsForCommodity.ContainsKey(commodity))
        {
            List<Bid> bids = _bidsForCommodity[commodity];
            ResolveRejectedBids(bids);
        }
        else if (_asksForCommodity.ContainsKey(commodity))
        {
            List<Ask> asks = _asksForCommodity[commodity];
            ResolveRejectedAsks(asks);
        }*/
    }
```

I also noticed, that this snippet

```
                    double totalTransactionPrice = clearingPrice * quantityTraded;
                    unitsSold += (int)quantityTraded;
                    averagePrice += totalTransactionPrice;
```

does not update the "averagePrice" value, when I debug line by line. It stays zero in this case, even though "totalTransactionPrice" is not. When I run the program without a prior breakpoint it seems to calculate the averagePrice fine. I don't unserstand.

Sorry for the mess btw. I didn't bother to clean it as it's throwaway by now.

Comment: I also noticed just now, that when running the same code again it prints averagePrice as 0 now, even though double.IsNan(averagePrice) is still true.

Comment: How is `averagePrice` being set in both of your tests?

Comment: @TimothyG. I've posted the full source method, sorry that it's a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was being dumb. Initially I assigned averagePrice in the Watchlist in Visual Studio Code and while experimenting because it didn't seem to work the way I expected I've done this piece of art:

[image: averagePrice = 0;]

I've deleted this and now it behaves properly. Probably should have been averagePrice == 0 to begin with.